# ¿Cómo utilizar Shinycssloaders desde el comienzo de la carga de la función fileInput()?

Tags: r, shiny

Estoy implementando una aplicación con Shiny y necesito cargar un archivo, para eso estoy usando la función fileInput aunque no necesariamente tengo que usar esta función, y quiero usar una función del paquete shinycssloaders mientras el archivo se está cargando. Mi problema es que quiero obtener una rueda giratoria inmediatamente después de seleccionar un archivo, pero esta rueda comienza a aparecer algún tiempo después de haber seleccionado el archivo, especialmente cuando el archivo es grande.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("data", label = "Select a file")),
    mainPanel(
      shinycssloaders::withSpinner(DT::DTOutput("table"), caption = "Loading...")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=300*1024^5)
  data <- reactive({
    validate(need(input$data, 'Please, select a file to start'))  
    shinycssloaders::showPageSpinner(caption = "Loading data...")
    datos <- vroom::vroom(input$data$datapath, delim = ",")
    shinycssloaders::hidePageSpinner()
    return(datos)
  })
  output$table <- DT::renderDT(
    dplyr::sample_n(data(), 100),
    filter = "top",
    options = list(pageLength = 10,
                   extensions = 'Responsive')
  )
}
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Cualquier solución es bienvenida, muchas gracias.